# Android-NDK установлен, но python его не видит

Tags: python, android-ndk, buildozer

На моём пк установлен Android NDK как для windows, так и для linux, но когда я ввожу команду в ubuntu для windows

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

Мне выводится вот это

```
 Android NDK is missing, downloading
# Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vova/.local/bin/buildozer", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1059, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 102, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 176, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 521, in install_platform
    self._install_android_ndk()
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 331, in _install_android_ndk
    self.buildozer.download(url,
  File "/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 687, in download
    urlretrieve(url, filename, report_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1855, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py", line 612, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: read of closed file
```

Помогите пожалуйста, как это лечится, буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса

```
pip install -U python-for-android
```

Comment: мне сообщается что уже всё установлено, ошибка в том что файл закрыт, Vallue error : read of  closed file. А ещё дело в том, что он пишет AndroidNDK is missing, я вот это пытаюсь избежать, либо мне надо самому это установить, либо наверное "открыть" файл, я новичок, не знаю в чём суть

Comment: И ещё я не указал, что работаю в терминале Ubuntu, а не в командной строке windows. Ошибка та же остаётся.